# ASp.net mvc Url Routing Problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I have a route setting for Profile controller
In order to view the profile page like http://localhost/Profile/MyUserName

```
routes.MapRoute("Profile", "Profile/{userName}", new { controller = "Profile", action = "Index", userName = "" });
```

These works fine.

My problem is that because the profile controller has many actions
Like... Profile/Edit,
Profile/Save,
Profile/Updates,
Profile/etc.... so on..
All of these actions got hit in the route "Profile/{userName}". 
In order to fix it i have to map all of these actions in the route table which is very ugly bec. i only want to map the route "Profile/{username}"

Is there a way that i can map only 1 route to profile controller and the rest i dont care about their url format?

im using mvc 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead Profile/{userName} I'm using Profile/View/{userName}. In this way I avoid case, when username is Edit or Save.

Comment: Thanks petch... i guess i should add unique url path in order to avoid clash of routes.. i just thought i wanted to make my url shorter and clean that's why.